# Cant run the code, intelij run arrow is 'grey'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZB8n.png)    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class EnglishCheckers {

    // Global constants
    public static final int RED   = 1;
    public static final int BLUE  = -1;
    public static final int EMPTY = 0;

    public static final int SIZE  = 8;

    // You can ignore these constants
    public static final int MARK  = 3;
    public static EnglishCheckersGUI grid;

    public static Scanner getPlayerFullMoveScanner = null;
    public static Scanner getStrategyScanner = null;

    public static final int RANDOM          = 1;
    public static final int DEFENSIVE       = 2;
    public static final int SIDES               = 3;
    public static final int CUSTOM          = 4;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ******** Don't delete ********* 
        // CREATE THE GRAPHICAL GRID
        grid = new EnglishCheckersGUI(SIZE);
        // ******************************* 


        //showBoard(example);
        //printMatrix(example);

        //interactivePlay();
        //twoPlayers();


        /* ******** Don't delete ********* */    
        if (getPlayerFullMoveScanner != null){
            getPlayerFullMoveScanner.close();
        }
        if (getStrategyScanner != null){
            getStrategyScanner.close();
        }
        /* ******************************* */

    }


    public static int[][] createBoard() {
        int[][] board = null;
        board=new int[8][8]; // defines the new length of the array
        for (int j=0; j<8; j=j+1)
        {
            for (int m=0; m<8; m=m+1) // these two "for" loops will set the value of each square of the board according to the instructions regarding it's location.
            {
                if (j==0|j==2)
                {
                    if (m%2==0)
                        board[j][m]=1;
                    else
                        board[j][m]=0;
                }
                if (j==1)
                {
                    if (m%2!=0)
                        board[j][m]=1;
                    else
                        board[j][m]=0;
                }
                if (j>2&j<5)
                    board[j][m]=0;
                if (j==5|j==7)
                {
                    if (m%2!=0)
                        board[j][m]=-1;
                    else
                        board[j][m]=0;
                }
                if (j==6)
                {
                    if (m%2==0)
                        board[j][m]=-1;
                    else
                        board[j][m]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        return board;
    }
    public static int howManyDiscs (int[][] board, int player){ // this function will return the number of discs a player has on the board
        int positive=0;
        int negative=0;
        for (int i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<8; j=j+1)
            {
                if (board[i][j]>0) positive=positive+1;
                if (board[i][j]<0) negative=negative+1;
            }
        }
        if (player>0) return positive;
        else return negative;       
    }
    public static int[][] playerDiscs(int[][] board, int player) {
        int[][] positions = null;
        if (howManyDiscs(board,player)>0)
        {
            positions=new int[howManyDiscs(board,player)][2]; // defines the new length of the array
            int line=0;
            for (int i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
            {
                for (int j=0; j<8; j=j+1)
                {
                    if (player>0&&board[i][j]>0) // will update the array if the player is 1
                    {
                        positions[line][0]=i;
                        positions[line][1]=j;
                        line=line+1;                        
                    }
                    if (player<0&&board[i][j]<0) // will update the array if the player is (-1)
                    {
                        positions[line][0]=i;
                        positions[line][1]=j;
                        line=line+1;                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return positions;
    }
    public static boolean isBasicMoveValid(int[][] board, int player, int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
        boolean ans = false;
        if (fromRow>=0&&fromRow<8&&fromCol>=0&&fromCol<8&&toRow>=0&&toRow<8&&toCol>=0&&toCol<8) // makes sure the coordinates are legal
        {
            if (board[fromRow][fromCol]==player|board[fromRow][fromCol]==player*2) // checks if a disc of the player exists in the origin square
            {
                if(board[toRow][toCol]==0) // checks if the destination square is legal
                {
                    if (toCol==fromCol+1||toCol==fromCol-1) // checks if the destination column is legal
                    {
                        if (toRow==fromRow+1&&player!=-1) // makes sure the move is legal for a player that isn't (-1)
                        {
                            ans=true;
                        }
                        if (toRow==fromRow-1&&player!=1) // makes sure the move is legal for a player that isn't 1
                        {
                            ans=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
    public static int[][] getAllBasicMoves(int[][] board, int player) {
        int[][] moves = null;
        int line=0;
        for (int i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<8; j=j+1) // these 2 "for" loops will add 1 to the counter "line" for each legal move a square has
            {
                if (isBasicMoveValid(board,player,i,j,i+1,j+1)) line=line+1;
                if (isBasicMoveValid(board,player,i,j,i+1,j-1)) line=line+1;
                if (isBasicMoveValid(board,player,i,j,i-1,j+1)) line=line+1;
                if (isBasicMoveValid(board,player,i,j,i-1,j-1)) line=line+1;
            }
        }
        moves=new int[line][4]; // creating the length of the output array according to the amount of possibilities found
        line=0;
        for (int i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<8; j=j+1) // the if's below will insert every move that exists for each square to the array
            {
                if (isBasicMoveValid(board,player,i,j,i+1,j+1))
                {
                    moves[line][0]=i;
                    moves[line][1]=j;
                    moves[line][2]=i+1;
                    moves[line][3]=j+1;
                    line=line+1;
                }   
                if (isBasicMoveValid(board,player,i,j,i+1,j-1))
                {
                    moves[line][0]=i;
                    moves[line][1]=j;
                    moves[line][2]=i+1;
                    moves[line][3]=j-1;
                    line=line+1;
                }   
                if (isBasicMoveValid(board,player,i,j,i-1,j+1))
                {
                    moves[line][0]=i;
                    moves[line][1]=j;
                    moves[line][2]=i-1;
                    moves[line][3]=j+1;
                    line=line+1;
                }   
                if (isBasicMoveValid(board,player,i,j,i-1,j-1))
                {
                    moves[line][0]=i;
                    moves[line][1]=j;
                    moves[line][2]=i-1;
                    moves[line][3]=j-1;
                    line=line+1;
                }
            }
        }
        return moves;
    }
    public static boolean isBasicJumpValid(int[][] board, int player, int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
        boolean ans = false;
        if (fromRow>=0&&fromRow<8&&fromCol>=0&&fromCol<8&&toRow>=0&&toRow<8&&toCol>=0&&toCol<8) // makes sure the coordinates are legal
        {
            if (board[fromRow][fromCol]==player|board[fromRow][fromCol]==player*2) // checks if a disc of the player exists in the origin square
            {
                if(board[toRow][toCol]==0) // checks if the destination square is legal
                {
                    if (toRow==fromRow+2)
                    {
                        if (toCol==fromCol+2)
                        {
                            if (player==1|player==2)
                            {
                                if (board[fromRow+1][fromCol+1]<0)
                                    ans=true;
                            }
                            if (player==-2)
                            {
                                if (board[fromRow+1][fromCol+1]>0)
                                    ans=true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (toCol==fromCol-2)
                        {
                            if (player==1|player==2)
                            {
                                if (board[fromRow+1][fromCol-1]<0)
                                    ans=true;
                            }
                            if (player==-2)
                            {
                                if (board[fromRow+1][fromCol-1]>0)
                                    ans=true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (toRow==fromRow-2)
                    {
                        if (toCol==fromCol+2)
                        {
                            if (player==-1|player==-2)
                            {
                                if (board[fromRow-1][fromCol+1]>0)
                                    ans=true;
                            }
                            if (player==2)
                            {
                                if (board[fromRow-1][fromCol+1]<0)
                                    ans=true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (toCol==fromCol-2)
                        {
                            if (player==-1|player==-2)
                            {
                                if (board[fromRow-1][fromCol-1]>0)
                                    ans=true;
                            }
                            if (player==2)
                            {
                                if (board[fromRow-1][fromCol-1]<0)
                                    ans=true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
    public static int [][] getRestrictedBasicJumps(int[][] board, int player, int row, int col) {
        int[][] moves = null;
        int line=0;
        for (int i=row-2; i<=row+2; i=i+2)
        {
            for (int j=col-2; j<=col+2; j=j+2) // these 2 "for" loops will add 1 to the counter "line" for each legal move a square has
            {
                if (isBasicJumpValid(board,player,row,col,i,j)) line=line+1;
            }
        }
        moves=new int[line][4]; // creating the length of the output array according to the amount of possibilities found
        line=0;
        for (int i=row-2; i<=row+2; i=i+2)
        {
            for (int j=col-2; j<=col+2; j=j+2)
            {
                if (isBasicJumpValid(board,player,row,col,i,j)) // will insert every possible jump to the array
                {
                    moves[line][0]=row;
                    moves[line][1]=col;
                    moves[line][2]=i;
                    moves[line][3]=j;
                    line=line+1;
                }
            }
        }
        return moves;
    }
    public static int[][] getAllBasicJumps(int[][] board, int player) {
        int [][] moves = null;
        int [][] discs = playerDiscs(board,player); // this array holds a list of the discs the player has on the board currently
        int counter=0;
        for (int i=0; i<discs.length; i=i+1) // will add each disc's amount of possible moves to the counter
            counter=counter+getRestrictedBasicJumps(board,player,discs[i][0],discs[i][1]).length;
        moves=new int[counter][4]; // defining the array's size according to the sum of all discs possible jumps
        int line=0;
        for (int a=0; a<discs.length; a=a+1)
        {
            int [][] jumps = getRestrictedBasicJumps(board,player,discs[a][0],discs[a][1]); // creates the array "jumps" that holds the possible jumps for the current "for" disc
            for (int i=0; i<jumps.length; i=i+1) // will insert each line of the jumps array to the moves array
            {
                moves[line][0]=jumps[i][0];
                moves[line][1]=jumps[i][1];
                moves[line][2]=jumps[i][2];
                moves[line][3]=jumps[i][3];
                line=line+1;
            }
        }
        return moves;
    }
    public static boolean canJump(int[][] board, int player) {
        boolean ans = false;
        if (getAllBasicJumps(board,player).length>0) ans=true;
        return ans;
    }
    public static boolean isMoveValid(int[][] board, int player, int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
        boolean ans = false;
        if (isBasicJumpValid(board,player,fromRow,fromCol,toRow,toCol)) 
            ans=true;
        else
            if (isBasicMoveValid (board,player,fromRow,fromCol,toRow,toCol)) 
                ans=true;
        return ans;
    }
    public static boolean hasValidMoves(int[][] board, int player) {
        boolean ans = false;
        if (getAllBasicMoves(board,player).length>0) ans=true;
        if (canJump(board,player)) ans=true;
        return ans;
    }
    public static int[][] playMove(int[][] board, int player, int fromRow, int fromCol, int toRow, int toCol) {
        if (isBasicJumpValid(board,player,fromRow,fromCol,toRow,toCol)) // in case it's a jump- will replace the eaten player with 0
        {
            if (fromRow>toRow)
            {
                if (fromCol>toCol) board[fromRow-1][fromCol-1]=0;
                else board[fromRow-1][fromCol+1]=0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (fromCol>toCol) board[fromRow+1][fromCol-1]=0;
                else board[fromRow+1][fromCol+1]=0;
            }
        }
        if (player==1&toRow==7)
        {
            board[toRow][toCol]=2;
            board[fromRow][fromCol]=0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (player==-1&toRow==0)
            {
                board[toRow][toCol]=-2;
                board[fromRow][fromCol]=0;
            }
            else
            {
                board[toRow][toCol]=player;
                board[fromRow][fromCol]=0;
            }
        }
        return board;
    }
    public static boolean gameOver(int[][] board, int player) {
        boolean ans = false;
        if (!hasValidMoves(board,player)) ans=true;
        if (playerDiscs(board,1)==null | playerDiscs(board,-1)==null) ans=true;
        return ans;
    }
    public static int findTheLeader(int[][] board) {
        int ans = 0;
        int player1=0, player2=0;
        for (int i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<8; j=j+1)
            {
                if (board[i][j]==1) player1=player1+1;
                if (board[i][j]==2) player1=player1+2;
                if (board[i][j]==-1) player1=player2+1;
                if (board[i][j]==-2) player1=player2+2;
            }
        }
        if (player1>player2) 
            ans=1;
        else
            if (player2>player1)
                ans=-1;
            else
                ans=0;
        return ans;
    }
    public static int[][] randomPlayer(int[][] board, int player) {
        if (hasValidMoves(board,player))
        {
            if (getAllBasicMoves(board,player).length>0 && isMoveValid(board,player,getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][0],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][1],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][2],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][3]))
                board=playMove(board,player,getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][0],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][1],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][2],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][3]);
            else
            if (getAllBasicJumps(board,player).length>0 && isMoveValid(board,player,getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][0],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][1],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][2],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][3]))
                board=playMove(board,player,getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][0],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][1],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][2],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][3]);
        }
        return board;
    }
    public static int[][] defensivePlayer(int[][] board, int player) {
        if (hasValidMoves(board,player))
        {
            if (canJump(board,player))
                board=playMove(board,player,getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][0],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][1],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][2],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][3]);
            else
            {
                boolean goodMove=false;
                int i=0;
                int [][] arr=board;
                while (i<getAllBasicMoves(board,player).length && !goodMove)
                {
                    arr=playMove(board,player,getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i][0],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i][1],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i][2],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i][3]);
                    if (!canJump(arr,-player))
                        goodMove=true;
                    i=i+1;
                }
                board=arr;
            }
        }
        return board;
    }
    public static int[][] sidesPlayer(int[][] board, int player) {

        if (hasValidMoves(board,player))
        {
            if (canJump(board,player))
                board=playMove(board,player,getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][0],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][1],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][2],getAllBasicJumps(board,player)[0][3]);
            else
            {
                if (getAllBasicMoves(board,player).length>1)
                {
                    int bestMove=0, minHefresh=7;
                    for (int i=1; i<getAllBasicMoves(board,player).length; i=i+1)
                    {
                        if (Math.abs(0-getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i][3])<minHefresh)
                        {
                            bestMove=i;
                            minHefresh=Math.abs(0-getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i][3]);
                        }
                        if (Math.abs(0-getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i-1][3])<minHefresh)
                        {
                            bestMove=i-1;
                            minHefresh=Math.abs(0-getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i-1][3]);
                        }
                        if (Math.abs(7-getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i][3])<minHefresh)
                        {
                            bestMove=i;
                            minHefresh=Math.abs(7-getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i][3]);
                        }
                        if (Math.abs(7-getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i-1][3])<minHefresh)
                        {
                            bestMove=i-1;
                            minHefresh=Math.abs(7-getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[i-1][3]);
                        }
                    }
                    board=playMove(board,player,getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[bestMove][0],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[bestMove][1],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[bestMove][2],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[bestMove][3]);
                }
                else
                    board=playMove(board,player,getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][0],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][1],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][2],getAllBasicMoves(board,player)[0][3]);
            }
        }
        return board;
    }












    //******************************************************************************//

    /* ---------------------------------------------------------- *
     * Play an interactive game between the computer and you      *
     * ---------------------------------------------------------- */
    public static void interactivePlay() {
        int[][] board = createBoard();
        showBoard(board);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the interactive Checkers Game !");

        int strategy = getStrategyChoice();
        System.out.println("You are the first player (RED discs)");

        boolean oppGameOver = false;
        while (!gameOver(board, RED) && !oppGameOver) {
            board = getPlayerFullMove(board, RED);

            oppGameOver = gameOver(board, BLUE);
            if (!oppGameOver) {
                EnglishCheckersGUI.sleep(200);

                board = getStrategyFullMove(board, BLUE, strategy);
            }
        }

        int winner = 0;
        if (playerDiscs(board, RED).length == 0  |  playerDiscs(board, BLUE).length == 0){
            winner = findTheLeader(board);
        }

        if (winner == RED) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("\t *************************");
            System.out.println("\t * You are the winner !! *");
            System.out.println("\t *************************");
        }
        else if (winner == BLUE) {
            System.out.println("\n======= You lost :( =======");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("\n======= DRAW =======");
    }


    /* --------------------------------------------------------- *
     * A game between two players                                *
     * --------------------------------------------------------- */
    public static void twoPlayers() {
        int[][] board = createBoard();
        showBoard(board);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the 2-player Checkers Game !");

        boolean oppGameOver = false;
        while (!gameOver(board, RED)  &  !oppGameOver) {
            System.out.println("\nRED's turn");
            board = getPlayerFullMove(board, RED);

            oppGameOver = gameOver(board, BLUE);
            if (!oppGameOver) {
                System.out.println("\nBLUE's turn");
                board = getPlayerFullMove(board, BLUE);
            }
        }

        int winner = 0;
        if (playerDiscs(board, RED).length == 0  |  playerDiscs(board, BLUE).length == 0)
            winner = findTheLeader(board);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t ************************************");
        if (winner == RED)
            System.out.println("\t * The red player is the winner !!  *");
        else if (winner == BLUE)
            System.out.println("\t * The blue player is the winner !! *");
        else
            System.out.println("\t * DRAW !! *");
        System.out.println("\t ************************************");
    }


    /* --------------------------------------------------------- *
     * Get a complete (possibly a sequence of jumps) move        *
     * from a human player.                                      *
     * --------------------------------------------------------- */
    public static int[][] getPlayerFullMove(int[][] board, int player) {
        // Get first move/jump
        int fromRow = -1, fromCol = -1, toRow = -1, toCol = -1;
        boolean jumpingMove = canJump(board, player);
        boolean badMove   = true;
        getPlayerFullMoveScanner = new Scanner(System.in);//I've modified it
        while (badMove) {
            if (player == 1){
                System.out.println("Red, Please play:");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Blue, Please play:");
            }

            fromRow = getPlayerFullMoveScanner.nextInt();
            fromCol = getPlayerFullMoveScanner.nextInt();

            int[][] moves = jumpingMove ? getAllBasicJumps(board, player) : getAllBasicMoves(board, player);
            markPossibleMoves(board, moves, fromRow, fromCol, MARK);
            toRow   = getPlayerFullMoveScanner.nextInt();
            toCol   = getPlayerFullMoveScanner.nextInt();
            markPossibleMoves(board, moves, fromRow, fromCol, EMPTY);

            badMove = !isMoveValid(board, player, fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol); 
            if (badMove)
                System.out.println("\nThis is an illegal move");
        }

        // Apply move/jump
        board = playMove(board, player, fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol);
        showBoard(board);

        // Get extra jumps
        if (jumpingMove) {
            boolean longMove = (getRestrictedBasicJumps(board, player, toRow, toCol).length > 0);
            while (longMove) {
                fromRow = toRow;
                fromCol = toCol;

                int[][] moves = getRestrictedBasicJumps(board, player, fromRow, fromCol);

                boolean badExtraMove = true;
                while (badExtraMove) {
                    markPossibleMoves(board, moves, fromRow, fromCol, MARK);
                    System.out.println("Continue jump:");
                    toRow = getPlayerFullMoveScanner.nextInt();
                    toCol = getPlayerFullMoveScanner.nextInt();
                    markPossibleMoves(board, moves, fromRow, fromCol, EMPTY);

                    badExtraMove = !isMoveValid(board, player, fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol); 
                    if (badExtraMove)
                        System.out.println("\nThis is an illegal jump destination :(");
                }

                // Apply extra jump
                board = playMove(board, player, fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol);
                showBoard(board);

                longMove = (getRestrictedBasicJumps(board, player, toRow, toCol).length > 0);
            }
        }
        return board;
    }


    /* --------------------------------------------------------- *
     * Get a complete (possibly a sequence of jumps) move        *
     * from a strategy.                                          *
     * --------------------------------------------------------- */
    public static int[][] getStrategyFullMove(int[][] board, int player, int strategy) {
        if (strategy == RANDOM)
            board = randomPlayer(board, player);
        else if (strategy == DEFENSIVE)
            board = defensivePlayer(board, player);
        else if (strategy == SIDES)
            board = sidesPlayer(board, player);

        showBoard(board);
        return board;
    }


    /* --------------------------------------------------------- *
     * Get a strategy choice before the game.                    *
     * --------------------------------------------------------- */
    public static int getStrategyChoice() {
        int strategy = -1;
        getStrategyScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Choose the strategy of your opponent:" +
                "\n\t(" + RANDOM + ") - Random player" +
                "\n\t(" + DEFENSIVE + ") - Defensive player" +
                "\n\t(" + SIDES + ") - To-the-Sides player player");
        while (strategy != RANDOM  &  strategy != DEFENSIVE
                &  strategy != SIDES) {
            strategy=getStrategyScanner.nextInt();
        }
        return strategy;
    }


    /* --------------------------------------- *
     * Print the possible moves                *
     * --------------------------------------- */
    public static void printMoves(int[][] possibleMoves) {
        for (int i = 0;  i < 4;  i = i+1) {
            for (int j = 0;  j < possibleMoves.length;  j = j+1)
                System.out.print(" " + possibleMoves[j][i]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    /* --------------------------------------- *
     * Mark/unmark the possible moves          *
     * --------------------------------------- */
    public static void markPossibleMoves(int[][] board, int[][] moves, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int value) {
        for (int i = 0;  i < moves.length;  i = i+1)
            if (moves[i][0] == fromRow  &  moves[i][1] == fromColumn)
                board[moves[i][2]][moves[i][3]] = value;

        showBoard(board);
    }


    /* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
     * Shows the board in a graphic window                                         *
     * you can use it without understanding how it works.                          *                                                     
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    public static void showBoard(int[][] board) {
        grid.showBoard(board);
    }


    /* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
     * Print the board                                                             *
     * you can use it without understanding how it works.                          *                                                     
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
        for (int i = matrix.length-1; i >= 0; i = i-1){
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j = j+1){
                System.out.format("%4d", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

hi. just started coding for , installed ide intellij but i cant run the code.
thanks so much!

As you can see the green arrow of the run command is disabled. in addition when i try to run from the run menu of the toolbar it just says edit configuration.

[image: As you can see the green arrow of the run command is disabled. in addition when i try to run from the run menu of the toolbar it just says edit configuration]

Comment: looks like you need to set up a run configuration

Comment: Is your `.java` file in a source directory? If it's not, neither of the posted solutions will work (and neither will most of the features of IntelliJ)

Comment: The file is not inside the source root, it's the same problem as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891) and the same answer will work for you.

Comment: See also this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0efB_CKOYo.

Answer (score 1):

Just place cursor to the "main" method line and press right button and select run.

Comment: No, it will not work since the Java file is outside of the source root, you can tell it by the file icon in the tab. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891).

Comment: @CrazyCoder hi mate , well my settings are the same as in the video , and it still dosent work whats the next move?

Comment: See the link to the duplicate.

Comment: @CrazyCoder i unistalled and installed everything again. i sure that i configured the path good cause in the CMD i can run java.
in intellij i configured the jdk, and i can run some code. but if i try to open java files, not create new ones but open the ones i already have, i get a yellow line which prompts that i need to configure sdk.

Comment: Yes, you need JDK configured to build and run your files.

Comment: @CrazyCoder can u send me link to an explanation on how to do it? because as i mentioned above im sure i configured the sdk correctly . thanks

Comment: Show the screenshots with your project structure, modules and SDK configurations, also show the new editor screenshot that will confirm that the file is the source root now.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in main method code and tap Run.