# Intellij is unable to detect compile time errors

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, plugins, sdk, intellij-plugin

[This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3FRC.png)[It should be showing the highlighted line as error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F7zS.png)I tried to configure the intellij platform plugin sdk for my maven project,  but  it did not fix rhe problem.

I checked the jdk path and it's pointing to the right place.

I am completely lost on how to resolve this and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not clear what is the problem, maybe you could share the screenshots or other details?

Comment: Auto complete and error detection doesnt seem to work. So for exampke if i miss a semicolon it should show that as an error in red in the editor but it does not indicate anything. Also, if i create an object of a class it should display the methods that i can call using the dot operator. That doesnt work either.

Comment: Java files in the source roots? Power save mode not enabled?

Comment: Power save mode is disabled

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891 is the case.

Comment: No all the files are within source root

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).