# How to import zookeeper source code to idea

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-zookeeper

[image]

I get the following error, as the picture show, idea cannot identity any class , cannot find any declaration to go. so, what should i do to make it work

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have imported zookeeper source code in 2 steps:
1. run ant-eclipse command.    This will build eclipse meta files for project.
2. import eclipse project into intellij.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need modify `build.xml`,
find the text

```
<get src="https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ant-eclipse/ant-eclipse/1.0/ant-clipse-1.0.bin.tar.bz2"
```

change http protocol to https protocol.

Then run the command `ant eclipse` under the zookeeper root directory, it will automatically download ant-eclipse plugin and build the source code to an eclipse project.

After that, you just import zookeeper from IntelliJ IDEA as below.
[image]

Do remember that you should active `Eclipse Integration` plugin in IDEA.