# Intellij IDEA not performing code inspections

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I use Intellij IDEA for python, and it used to show every error I made on it. For some reason now, even if I do something that is clearly wrong, that check mark on the side always shows up. I tried fixing it, but that didn't work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891. Also make sure Power Save mode is not enabled in the File menu.