# Iintellij 2017 Java projects incompatible with IntelliJ 2018?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a series of Java projects created with Intellij 2017.3 and am trying to reopen them with  IntelliJ 2018. So far I am unsuccessful - what was a properly working project in 2017 opens without a "configuration" (though there was a valid configuration in 2017) and the project file tree is shown with a yellow background

[image: yellow background on Project Files view]

I've also tried to 'import' the project and create from existing sources, but the former apparently only works for projects created with external tools (e.g. Eclipse, etc.) and from 'existing sources' which likewise does not create a complete project.

I've not been successful finding any help on Google or the JetBrains website.

Somehow this doesn't seem right. Could it be a defect?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891 and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Comment: Thanks, @CrazyCoder. This gave me some clues and I've sorta got it working, but I'm still puzzled that simply trying to open an existing project created by an earlier version of the same IDE would require such manual configuration. Other IDEs that I've used are capable of doing this - why not IntelliJ? Clearly, I'm missing something.

Comment: You have 2 `.iml` files for the apparently single module project, not sure which of them was imported, probably it contained invalid configuration.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, no, there's only 1 .iml file in each of the project directories. There's something else going on.

Comment: Feel free to report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project to reproduce attached.