# Cannot resolve symbol "CollectNewspaperKarel"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, karel

I've been trying to make CS106A work on my computer for ages, and it seems that I am missing out on a huge part of my Java education, because I keep on hearing stuff about dependencies, and classpaths, and have entered in too many lines into cmd that I have no idea what they did.

My most recent problem has been when I was merely testing the Karel program, I imported it like it said I should on IntelliJ's website, and I think I got most things right, the karel.jar is in the dependencies tab and whatnot, but when I try to run this code it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'CollectNewspaperKarel', I have no idea what its referring to, and all the other answers that I've seen talk in some gibberish that I don't understand. So if someone could explain to me the massive hole in my knowledge, or at least what its called so I can watch a video on it... that would be great. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```java
/*
 * File: CollectNewspaperKarel.java
 * --------------------------------
 * At present, the CollectNewspaperKarel subclass does nothing.
 * Your job in the assignment is to add the necessary code to
 * instruct Karel to walk to the door of its house, pick up the
 * newspaper (represented by a beeper, of course), and then return
 * to its initial position in the upper left corner of the house.
 */

import stanford.karel.*;

public class CollectNewspaperKarel extends Karel {
    public void run() {
        move();
        turnRight();
        move();
        turnLeft();
        move();
        pickBeeper();
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't show a load of print screens. show us the actual code. chances are, you are initializing it wrong, or you don't have a correct import statement

Comment: @Stultuske apologies, however, what are the chances where, the code is at the bottom, how have I imported it wrong? and whats initializing...

Comment: @AgustinFitipaldi please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891

Comment: Which class/line shows the error? I don't think it appears in `CollectNewspaperKarel` class.

Comment: @AgustinFitipaldi are you actually using a professional IDE while not knowing what initialization is?? how did you manage to compile the class, if it doesn't compile???

Comment: @Jai no line shows the error, that's part of the problem, it only arises when I go to compile and run it, as shown in the 3rd screenshot

Comment: @Stultuske I didn't manage to compile the class, thats where I'm having trouble, if you're asking about the CollectNewspaperKarel.class, that was already there.

Comment: @AgustinFitipaldi that .class file IS the compiled version. Do you know the very basics of how Java works?

Comment: @Stultuske hehehe, apparently not, but back to actually solving issues, would you mind explaining what this is all about?

Comment: well ... this is about you using tools you don't understand, and wondering why you can't get it to work. it's really as simple as that. Your description is vague at best, and you yourself indicate you don't have the basic knowledge you would need to even get to such kind of error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have another class that holds the application entry point (i.e. the `static main()` method). That class definitely used the `CollectNewspaperKarel` class, which you probably did not even place in `src` folder.

Comment: @Jai Thank you for being helpful, and this brings me to my next question, I remember making a project file and seeing that src folder, but I cant seem to find it in IntelliJ, when I find such a folder, would I merely transport all the class files over there?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, thank you for answering the obvious, I don't understand. However, I would greatly appreciate it if you could, instead of remind me of the fact that I am just learning this language, actually help me in answering my question. Which sounds like shouldn't be a problem for you

Comment: @AgustinFitipaldi there are only so many ways I can tell you that you haven't provided nearly enough information. Seriously, if you want to avoid issues like this: uninstall IntelliJ, buy a good textbook on Java, or go through the official documentation, and learn Java from the beginning

Comment: @Stultuske pardon, let me tell you where I am, I have begun taking the CS106A (Programming Methodology class at Stanford, supposedly requires no previous experience), I have gotten "The Art and Science of Java" Textbook for that class. I'm not sure what more information I can give you. I have a .java file I want to compile in an imported project file, and its giving me said error

Comment: what do you mean "I want to compile IN AN IMPORTED PROJECT"? You are not supposed to change anything about imported projects. Your code goes in your own.
btw, just took a glance over the book you're following. I'm starting to understand why you don't know the basics. Your teacher has you (from moment 1) using inheritance without as much as bothering to explain what it is/does.

Comment: @Stultuske Hahahahaha, it seems like there's a whole fuckbucket of stuff wrong then. What course of learning would you suggest so that I learn Java properly?

Comment: I would recommend a decent textbook on Java. What you get is 'call a method that runs code, without bothering what that code is, or how it works', the idea is you write the code to run. 'Java the complete reference' comes to mind. Also, following the official tutorials might help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/