# How do I create a Kotlin project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

None of the instructions available on the JetBrains website or elsewhere allow me to create a Kotlin project, so I assume (as a beginner to Kotlin) I must be missing something. The process of new project creation in JetBrains IDE's is generally quite straightforward and natural (e.g. Python in PyCharm, or even Haskell or Mathematica in IntelliJ); but with Kotlin, I always reach a dead end.

In IntelliJ I'm given several choices for creating a new project, For example, I can select "Kotlin" and choose one of the options there (e.g. "JVM | IDEA")

[image]

or choose "Java" and then "Kotlin/JVM"

[image]

but in both cases, I then arrive at a dead end, unable to create a new Kotlin source (`.kt`) file to begin my project, since no such file is among the choices presented:

[image]

Confusingly, I *am* able to add Kotlin source files to non Kotlin projects (e.g. Mathematica):

[image]

What am I missing? What is the correct way to create a basic Kotlin project in IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you create the file in the source root? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I checked the box to create a content root in `src`, and attempt to create the file there.

Comment: Make sure the directory you are creating the file in is marked as Source root and is displayed in blue color in the project view.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Interesting: There appears to be a bug. The project creation process offers an option (which I select, and is selected by default) to "create a source root", but that doesn't happen. Though the directory is created, it is not marked as a source root.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce: https://i.imgur.com/rE20IEC.png
https://i.imgur.com/WWCbPFF.png.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Any thoughts on why my IDE would be failing to mark the created directory as a source root? Could other plugins be interfering (e.g., Mathematica, Haskell), or could there be a setting somewhere that got flipped into the wrong state?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT with the steps to reproduce, sample project attached and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never and it *still* applies because the intellij documentation is still s**it.

- I am using Intellij Ultimate 2021.2.

If you are a newbie you MUST follow the following in order to be able to write your "Hello World" application:

[image]

Why? Because otherwise the following happens:

1. You will need to configure Gradle or Maven
2. For some god knows what reason, you will then have to configure your **project structure** which I tried, and I could not get *println* to resolve even
3. You will have errors saying the JVM is not configured

Why on Earth!! Intellij designers opt for this setup method is beyond me...cause I am using the Ultimate edition and it still is like this...so if you are using the community edition, it will be the same I am guessing.

I have now spent 2 hours trying to figure out why each project I have so far created with the defaults is not resolving the code in the 5 lines of code.
Anyhooo, if you follow the above, what you get is this:
[image]

And **NOT THIS::**
[image]