# Alt+Enter stopped showing Create Method in IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: intellij-idea, keymaps

I am using IntelliJ Community Edition ( 2019.2 version ).  Since this morning, when I type a method call with parameters and click Alt+Enter, it doesn't show me the option to create the method - I do not know what I may have done that I lost this functionality and have been unable to find out how to get the functionality back.  What do I need to do?

Hope there is a solution to this.

@crazycoder - Attaching image
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. If the issue persists, attach the screenshot of the IDE window showing where the issue occurs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891 may be the case.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Tried the invalidate and restart.  That did not fix it.  I have attached what I am getting.  Also, I was able to define the getSubdomainToTopicMapping() method earlier in the same class.  Not sure what I did to lose the functionality

Comment: There is a syntax issue in the code, try removing `String` in the method arguments as you don't specify the type when calling a method.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  Can you put it as an answer so that I can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax issue in the code, try removing the `String` part in the method arguments list as you don't need to specify the type when calling a method.