# IntelliJ "Cannot find declaration to go to" problem in Java projects with Bazel

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel, intellij-plugin

Recently we switched to use Bazel to build projects in Java. With Bazel, I can no longer use IntelliJ to explore the class declaration etc.. IntelliJ always prompts "Cannot find declaration to go to". I am wondering if anyone has got solution for this problem.

I encounter this issue in both IntelliJ 2019.1 and 2019.2.  The problem can be reproduced with https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/master/java-tutorial.

Comment: Do you get the source roots configured correctly when the project is imported? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891.

Comment: Please file a bug on https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij with your Bazel, OS, IntelliJ and plugin versions.