# IntelliJ Java groovy missing library?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, libraries

So I have been using IntelliJ for a while now still don't know my way around but so far from what I know is good!

Somehow one day I opened it to start on a new project (I use java btw) the groovy library went missing. I downloaded a groovy package groovy-2.5.8 and finally could get a project started but now my class has this maroon colour and not its usual small green circle that shows the project can be compiled and run I guess. Does anybody know what I can do?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891 help?

Comment: it does thank you. But my .iml file is still maroon? and I followed all the steps that user9944315 said to do?

Comment: It may indicate version control status: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html

Comment: it says that "The file exists locally, but is not in the repository, and is not scheduled for addition." ? before I dealt with .iml files

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839

Comment: The article talks about sharing projects?? and what to do with each file

Comment: While learning things about how all that works is good, do yourself a favour and distance yourself from your IDE being your primary build tool. Once you feel good about Groovy and IntelliJ tip your toes in the ponds of Maven or Gradle. Let the IDE do what it's good at (edit/inspect/debug your code) but give the job to provide a sane build/run env to the tool made for it. Once you have to share your project with team members or your CI tool, you are in a world of pain if your IDE is the central hub.

Comment: Thank you for that information. but currently I am not good with groovy and IntelliJ and I have no projects to be sharing but the class is still shaded auburn/maroon if you do know how to handle that?