# Intellij IDEA not indexing tests folder

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a test folder under the src one, and IntelliJ is not formatting folders as packages correctly, nor showing test suites as classes. It is not even showing compiling errors in advance while editing, nor marking keywords with different colors.

Main sources are being indexed correctly.

I'm under gradle 5 and Java 11 using Intellij IDEA 2019.3 Community Edition.

The path of my test files is: `src/test/java/com/example/Test.java`

Comment: Did you  specified  the test folder in the idea ui or in gradle?, add your gradle file to the question and your test folder path.

Comment: Seems to be a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307532/auto-errors-detection-in-intellij-idea/43319356#43319356

Comment: @DanielBoehm all my java files are under the sources folder

Comment: @Yan.F I specified the test folder in the UI. Not sure how to do it in the gradle file.