# When creating a new module it does not allow me to create class file

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Trying to create a new submodule(the second one in the picture)under the parent module(the first one in the picture), but when I right clicked the main file of it, it did not allow me to create class files. Created a submodule (the third one)before this, but did not encounter the same problem. Making it a source root resolved the problem, but I do not know what that really does to my project structure, so I am not willing to use that. You can also see that the second module does not come with a target file, and its resources folder looks different.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Target directory appears after you build the project. When a Java project is imported from `pom.xml`, default source and resource directories should be configured automatically for you. If you create a module manually without importing it from Maven, you have to set the source roots yourself. [See the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891) for details.