# I've been getting an error on IntelliJ saying Cannot Create Class with an odd Error message

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image][image: ava]

I've deleted and redone this a bunch of times and I can't create a simple class. If I set the src folder the root folder and run the Test.java it works, however it doesn't show the blue "C" icon and shows that rectangular "J" Icon for Test.java

How do I fix this?

Comment: Check your [class](https://i.imgur.com/ekd9HvV.png) and [header templates](https://i.imgur.com/XsxG0bY.png). It looks like invalid code gets generated. Restore the templates to the defaults.

Comment: Just tried it, it seemed like nothing happened

Comment: Please share the screenshots with these templates, the `Test.java` file contents and the exception from [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: Okay I uploaded the photo, I don't understand the idea.log file. I've found where it's located, should I send you screenshots of all the exceptions?

Comment: Upload the log somewhere, like https://pastebin.com/ and share a link. Did you try changing the project roots as suggested in my answer? You also didn't provide the file template for the java class and the code template for the include as shown on my comment screenshots.

Comment: Okay strangest thing happened, I just had my computer restarted and everything works just normal now. I have no idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The source roots are not configured correctly. Only `src` directory needs to be configured as the source root, not the root directory of your project.

See the related questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891