# How to edit configurations of IDE to run a java application...? (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know how to run my Java program from the command line. My path to `Main.java` is:

```
my_dir/turtlesolution
```

`turtlesolution` has the following:

```
Main.java
Turtle.java
Turtles.java
```

I opened `turtlesolution` as the project, using IntelliJ. I then opened (by double clicking) `Main.java`. I want to run this. I have to `edit configurations` before I run it, it seems.

So I clicked `edit configurations`. I clicked `JAR application` because this looks like the option. This is what comes up:

[image]

Working directory, I set it to point to `turtlesolution`. What is `Path to JAR`? I tried to set it to `turtlesolution` but it remains blank. What does `Warning, jar file doesn't exist` mean?

I can run it from the command line by just doing

```
cd turtlesolution
javac Main.java Turtle.java Turtles.java
cd ../
java turtlesolution/Main
```

Aapprently it's very easy to figure out. I'm in my final year of learning CS in university and apparently it's simple, but I can't figure out how to do it, and it's too simple to teach ...

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I've seen both. Neither answer the question.

Comment: @CrazyCoder The first seemed to explain how to run it if I start from scratch, but I an opening an existing `turtlesolution` project. The second just says "select desired configuration". I'm asking how exactly I should configure it to be able to make it run similar to how I do `javac` then `java turtlesolution/Main` from command line. Thanks!

Comment: Where does it say to use JAR Application? You just use the normal Application, also make sure you have the sources in the source root, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891.

Comment: Start from scratch as described in the help, then just copy your `.java` files to the **src** directory, then click on the green arrow on the left of the main method/class to run it.

Comment: Or right click on the directory with `.java` files, choose `Mark Directory as` | `Source Root`, then click on the green arrow on the left of the main class/method in the editor to run it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any run configuration in the project, Run button is also disabled.
If you right click in a file with main method, run configuration is created automatically and main class value if prefilled. This worked for me for more vist https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206811415-Problem-with-Edit-Configurations-