# How do I get IntelliJ to make code completion suggestions from other files in the package?

Tags: intellij-idea

For example, if I have a file (example is Kotlin):

```kotlin
package app

enum class Resources {
    Gold,
    Wood,
    Food
}
```

How can I make IntelliJ suggest `Resources.Gold`, `Resources.Wood`, and `Resources.Food` in another file? It was doing this for me at one point but for some reason it has suddenly stopped. I can't find anything about it in the Code Completion settings and nothing changed when I reinstalled IntelliJ nor when I restarted my computer.

Here is a screenshot of my IDE where I expect code completion (line 29):
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the IDE where you expect auto-completion?

Comment: Yup. I have edited my question.

Comment: Are you sure `src/main/kotlin` is set as the sources root? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891. Did Gradle import complete without errors? If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).