# Intellij Idea CE - how to run Java main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been using IntelliJ CE for a Spring Boot project. The Run/Debug has always been a little flaky, but I've usually been able to figure it out. But now, it's only giving the option to create a template. So I'm trying to create a template to run a Spring Boot application.

However, when I try to choose the main class, by navigating to it, the "OK" button is grayed out. The entries under "search by name" are items such as "Activation (sun.rmi.server)", and "Base64" (java.util.prefs)", which have nothing to do with my project.

It seems like this could be classloader issue, where IntelliJ is somehow using the wrong one, but I have no idea how to address it.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by template option? You can click the green arrow in the gutter on the left of the `main` method and run it, run configuration will be created automatically, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html . If you don't see the arrow, there is some issue with the project configuration like https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891. To get more help, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the screenshot of how the file looks like in the IDE.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Thanks for your help. There were no green arrows, unfortunately.  I ended up restoring the project from git. Then I copied a directory which I had added from a backup I made before the restore, and everything works again. I have to do this every once in a while with IntelliJ for some reason. As I get used to it, I hope to figure out what it is I'm doing wrong that constantly is corrupting the configuration.