# Why does IntelliJ not show the "System.out.println()" shortcut when I type "sout"?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When i type `sout` in IntelliJ, it doesn't show the `System.out.println()` shortcut, and instead shows `WSDLOutput`, `WSDLOutputImpl`, `JSWBlend_SRC_Outpeer`, and `LSOutput`.

Comment: hit Ctrl + J to see all available shortcuts

Comment: Make sure you have [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) enabled

Answer (score 3):

This live template works in Java files inside a method (not in the root of the class where there can be no executable code except the static initializer blocks).

So, make sure you are inside a method and also check [Java class in inside the sources root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891).

[image: sample]

Sample class to try:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sout <- press Tab here
    }
}
```

You can expand it using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Preferences -> Live Templates -> Java`. Check that you have the `sout` live template. If you don't, add a new live template under the `user` section with the abbreviation `sout` and the text `System.out.println()`.