# JetBrain's "TODO" highlighting not working

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, ide, highlight, todo

I recently decided to reinstall some of my IDEs as i wanted to get a clear installations.
I re-downloaded Pycharm and IntelliJ (community version) and found out that the "TODO" and "FIXME" tag highlighting doesn't work anymore.
The IDEs find the TODOs (i.e. when I go to the "TODO" tab I can see them), but they are not highlighted within the code itself.

- I checked the settings, and the patterns are all right (if they weren't it wouldn't find the TODOs anyways).
- I checked the color settings and they are set to be bold and orange.

With all of that in mind, the TODOs still look like regular comments on both IDEs and I find it difficult.

Image of the situation (FIXME not highlighting in code, looking like regular comment right after it, but it is recognize in the TODO tab):

[image]

Image of the TODO patterns in the settings tab:

[[image: ]2]

Image of the coloring settings:
[image]

Help would really be appreciated! :)

Comment: What is the file extension? Can you reproduce it in all the file types?

Comment: It doesn't work in IntelliJ with Java files, but does work with .py files.
It doesn't work in Pycharm with .py files, but works with java files.
I'm even more confused haha :)

Comment: We can't reproduce it: https://i.imgur.com/jee92P3.png. Does it work with the default TODO pattern? Does it help if you start with the default settings: File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png? Does the issue occur in the current 2021.1 release?

Comment: Doesn't work with the TODO pattern.
I restored the default settings and it didn't help.
(And its 2021.1 release)

Comment: Is there any reason for IntelliJ not to recognize Java files properly? Or for pycharm to not recognize python files?

Comment: One of the reasons would be https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891. If the file doesn't belong to a project (is located outside of the project roots and source roots), it will not be parsed).

Comment: Solved the issue thanks to you, it didn't recognize the Java files because I'm a fool and didn't put them into a module accidentally... wasted hours.

How can I gift you for helping me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231146/discussion-between-chocolatebear-and-crazycoder).