# I have a problem with INTELIJI IDEA. My classes are not recognized as classes by the IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

As you can see on the photo my classes are not recognized as such. Instead of having a "C" as an icon on the left, I have a "J", this is a problem for me because errors are not detected. What should I do ?

[image]

Comment: looks like `src` is not marked as a `source folder`

Comment: @Jens which mostly comes from loading project not from root directory .

Answer (score 2):

Its all about loading the project from root directory(Java project structor) so to detect src package of project, which fully explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/15758781)
[image: Java project structure]

Comment: thank you it was because the "save mode" was activated