# How to run maven command line tests in Intellij to resolve testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value ERROR

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, automated-tests

I have a maven project which can be run from command line (in IntelliJ). Yet, when I try to in the UI, I get the following error.

`testSuiteXmlFiles0 has null value`

Attached is the screenshot of error and maven runtime configuration. Again, the command line (in the runtime configuration) works fine from command line.

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/legacy/bddsSmoke.xml -Dbrowser=chrome -Denvironment=sit03
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure the working directory is set correctly, normally you would use `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$` macro. Not sure what `automation` represents on your screenshot. It should be the absolute path.

Comment: @CrazyCoder it's the MacOS equivalent filepath. Both that suggestion and the $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$ are not resolving. thanks

Comment: In this case please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also noticed that your project has no source roots configured. Make sure to import it from pom.xml, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start. At the current state the project will not work correctly in the IDE, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891.