# IntelliJ has no highlighting, command click etc

Tags: intellij-idea

I woke up this morning and my IntelliJ is suddenly behaving like a text editor:

1. No highlighting of functions, variables etc.
2. No `CMD + Click` mouse pointer changing to hand. If I press `CMD` and hover over a type, the mouse pointer doesn't change
3. No unit test detection.

Nothing's working. How do I fix this!
thanks

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891 look like your case?

Comment: It doesn't. I haven't moved any files. It's the same repo that I've been developing on for a year now.

Comment: Please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the screenshot of the IDE window and the editor, also attach the logs using Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to disable the Shared Project Indexes Plugin.

`Preferences -> Plugins -> Shared Project Indexes (uncheck it)` followed by a restart IDE.

My guess is that another project I recently opened messed with the indexes.