# IntelliJ Files not Running after I uploaded to OneDrive

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea

I had a simple Java class files in a project (really basic Java programming) on my local SSD. I uploaded them to OneDrive, but when I try to run these files from one drive, they no longer are able to run, and it says "Java file outside of source root", but when it runs on my local disk, it is able to run fine.

I tried copying an IML from a project that I created in OneDrive, but it still did not work, as the IML was the exact same.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891.