# IntelliJ won't import sources for ant build project

Tags: intellij-idea, ant

I'm trying to import an ant based project into IntelliJ, and it works, sort of. It looks like I have successfully imported the project, but the src directory does not show up, and if I manually open the files, and attempt to edit them, it warns me that I am editing non-project files.

I've tried to mark it as a source root, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#adding_content_root, but that option is not available.

I do have the ant plugin enabled. I am doing open project, and then it prompts to add the ant build file.

It looks like it adds all non-directories to the project window, but no directories, like "src".

Oddly, only the "release" target of the build file is available in the tool window. This works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please elaborate why mark as source root didn't work for you? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891. You can configure the module manually instead of importing.

Comment: Mark source root is not an option on any of the context menus. I have no problem doing this on non-ant projects.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could go to the File/Project Structure/Project Settings/Modules and create a module (there were none to start with), and point to the sources, then things started to work.

I also had to add necessary jar files to the dependency tab of the new module.