Intellij idea and version control and shortcuts
When I am cloning a git repository in intellij Idea the shortcuts are not activated like ctrl B and many others. The code also not highlighted in red and other colour. I used to go to functions directly using ctrl click or ctrl B but it is not working . How to solve please tell me
I tried with keymap configuration but not resolved

Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319356/104891 help?
